# How to fake user on staging environment with omniauth and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I use the developer provider for omniauth (with devise and rails 3) on local development environment and several provider on production. For the staging environment (manual integration test system) I would like to have something similar, where I can login with different users / providers simulating the authentication provider. How can I do that?